# Difference between `sed` command line and vim

Tags: vim, sed

On shell, I can get the following replacement :

```
echo '10**PM_dw2(np.log10(k_ref))' | sed 's/10\*\*PM_dw2(np.log10(\(.*\))/PM_dw2(\1/g'
```

Resutl : `PM_dw2(k_ref)`

But into Vim editor, I can't do the same thing. Example :

Text to replace with `10**PM_NW_dw2(np.log10(k_ref))` :

```
return ( P_obs_cross(k_ref, mu_ref,z,10**PM_dw2(np.log10(k_ref)),10**PM_NW_dw2(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop) -     8*P_obs_cross(k_ref,mu_ref,z,10**PM_dw(np.log10(k_ref)),10**PM_NW_dw(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop) + 8*P_obs_cros    s(k_ref,mu_ref,z,10**PM_up(np.log10(k_ref)),10**PM_NW_up(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop) - P_obs_cross(k_ref,mu_ref,    z,10**PM_up2(np.log10(k_ref)), 10**PM_NW_up2(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop)  ) / (12*omega_b_fid*eps_wb)
```

6

If I do under vim : `%s/10\*\*PM_dw2(np.log10(\(.*\))/PM_dw2(\1/g`

Then, I get :

```
   return ( P_obs_cross(k_ref, mu_ref,z,PM_dw2(k_ref)),10**PM_NW_dw2(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop) - 8*P_obs_cros    s(k_ref,mu_ref,z,10**PM_dw(np.log10(k_ref)),10**PM_NW_dw(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop) + 8*P_obs_cross(k_ref,mu_re    f,z,10**PM_up(np.log10(k_ref)),10**PM_NW_up(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop) - P_obs_cross(k_ref,mu_ref,z,10**PM_up2(    np.log10(k_ref)), 10**PM_NW_up2(np.log10(k_ref)), bias_s8, gf_s8, er_FH, er_FH_ref, er_FDA, er_FDA_ref, ir, jc, lc, iPop)  ) / (12*omega_b_fid*eps_wb
```

As you can see on the beginning of line, I have : `PM_dw2(k_ref))` whereas  I expect `PM_dw2(k_ref)` (no second parenthesis on the right).

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you have to use `.\{-}` instead of `.*` so it won't be greedy (see `:h greedy`)

Comment: Your question is a little bit confuse. You should try to provide some context, and provide a plain English explanation.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo . Thanks a lot, it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your `sed` input and the one in Vim is that the latter has multiple `(...)` parts inside the line.

The `(\(.*\))` part is a *greedy* match (due to the `*`); that means, it tries to match as many characters as possible (within a line, as `.` only matches characters other than the newline that ends a line).

So, your `sed` substitution suffers from the same problem, you just didn't notice it due to the different inputs.

#### Solution

There's a non-greedy variant of `*` (see [`:help pattern-multi-items`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern-multi-items)); in Vim's syntax, it's `\{-}`; many other regular expression dialects (e.g. in Perl) use `*?` instead. If you use that, as few characters as possible are matched, so it will stop at the next `)` instead of matching as many contained `)`'s to arrive at the last one in the line:

```
%s/10\*\*PM_dw2(np.log10(\(.\{-}\))/PM_dw2(\1/g
```

`sed`'s regular expressions only have greedy matches; one way to work around the problem there (in this particular case) is to modify the `.` atom instead, to a *character class* that excludes the `)` character: `[^)]*`.